# TikZ: Match up diagonal shading with adjacent horizontal and vertical three-colour shadings

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I apologize for the convoluted title, but I like my titles to describe my questions and couldn't think of a more condensed version.

Quite a few questions already exist on custom shadings and fadings for rectangles as well as other shapes, but I couldn't find the answer to my question in those. So here it is. I have two shaded rectangles that share a corner; the drawing is for a physics problem: the rectangles represent a floor and a wall. They have the same colour gradient except one is vertically oriented and the other horizontally. Now I want to join these two rectangles by means of a third rectangle with a similar diagonal gradient, but this has not worked.

I know the essence of *why* it doesn't work the way I currently have it implemented (if I'm not mistaken it has to do with the way TikZ obtains rotated shadings), but I'm unable to implement a working version. Below is a rendering of the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2em,y=2em]
% Dimensions of the stuff
\pgfmathsetmacro\floorL{7}
\pgfmathsetmacro\boxL{\floorL/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\boxH{\boxL/3.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wallH{2*\boxH}
\pgfmathsetmacro\floorD{\floorL/14}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wallD{\floorL/14}
% Define the stuff
% origin
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
% floor
\coordinate (floorTL) at (O);
\coordinate (floorTR) at ($(floorTL)+(\floorL,0)$);
\coordinate (floorBL) at ($(floorTL)+(0,-\floorD)$);
\coordinate (floorBR) at ($(floorBL)+(\floorL,0)$);
% wall
\coordinate (wallBL) at (floorTR);
\coordinate (wallBR) at ($(wallBL)+(\wallD,0)$);
\coordinate (wallTL) at ($(wallBL)+(0,\wallH)$);
\coordinate (wallTR) at ($(wallTL)+(\wallD,0)$);
% Draw the stuff
% floor
\fill[bottom color=white,top color=brown!60!black,middle color=brown!80] (floorBL) rectangle (floorTR);
% wall
\fill[left color=brown!60!black,right color=white,middle color=brown!80] (wallBL) rectangle (wallTR);
% connect wall and floor
\shade[left color=brown!60!black,right color=white,middle color=brown!80,shading angle=45] (floorBR) rectangle (wallBR);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would obviously like the colours to match up, so is this possible in some reasonably simple/elegant way?

Comment: I think the general principle is to make it a single shape and fill it once.

Comment: @Thruston I thought of that but unfortunately still couldn't figure out how I should then specify the shading to get the output that I'd like to have. Am I being blind here? I do need some sustenance :)

Answer (score 3):

Not quite what you asked for, but I'd suggest

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2em,y=2em]
% Dimensions of the stuff
\pgfmathsetmacro\floorL{7}
\pgfmathsetmacro\boxL{\floorL/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\boxH{\boxL/3.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wallH{2*\boxH}
\pgfmathsetmacro\floorD{\floorL/14}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wallD{\floorL/14}
% Define the stuff
% origin
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
% floor
\coordinate (floorTL) at (O);
\coordinate (floorTR) at ($(floorTL)+(\floorL,0)$);
\coordinate (floorBL) at ($(floorTL)+(0,-\floorD)$);
\coordinate (floorBR) at ($(floorBL)+(\floorL,0)$);
% wall
\coordinate (wallBL) at (floorTR);
\coordinate (wallBR) at ($(wallBL)+(\wallD,0)$);
\coordinate (wallTL) at ($(wallBL)+(0,\wallH)$);
\coordinate (wallTR) at ($(wallTL)+(\wallD,0)$);
% Draw the stuff
% floor
\shade [bottom color=white,top color=brown!60!black,middle color=brown!80] (floorBL) -- (wallBR |- floorBL) coordinate (c) -- (floorTR) -| cycle; 
% wall 
\shade [left color=brown!60!black,right color=white,middle color=brown!80] (wallBL) -- (c) -- (wallTR) -| cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @cfr hey this is tikz I'm just surprised to see output at all:- (feel free to edit my answer if it'll improve it)

Comment: Roll back if you don't like it. It is just a bit easier, I think. (Both to read and to think.)

Comment: No I'm sure it's fine, thanks:-) @cfr

Comment: That's a nice suggestion! I doubt what I'm looking for is impossible, but it could well be inconveniently cumbersome. Do you reckon that's the case or do you make this suggestion because you prefer the way this kind of wall-floor connection looks over the one I'm aiming for? In either case: would it be possible to get rid of the diagonal artefactual line?

Comment: @Wouter possibly I think it looks better (more like mitred wood join... but as cfr is gently hinting in the comments above I am rubbish at tikz so don't take my advice on what's possible, all I can say is that I managed to do this:-)

Comment: I can see what you mean, it does look a bit like that :) Well, I'll leave the question open - at least for now - but I'm using your suggestion as my current solution. Thanks!